# ARM assembly - invalid immediate operand value

Tags: arm

The question is "Store the data to the memory location 1001h, ..(1001h+10) and copy the data in reverse order in memory location 2001...(2001+h)" I keep getting the run time error invalid immediate operand value 
 *immediate must be creatable by rotating an 8-bit number right within a 32bit word*.
How do i fix it?

```
MVN R2,#0x1001
MOV R3,#0x2000
MOV R4,#0X01
MOV R0,#0X10


LOOP

    STRB R4,[R2]
    LDRB R5,[R2]
    STRB R0,[R3]
    ADD R2,R2,#0x01
    ADD R3,R3,#0x01
    ADD R4,R4, #0x01
    SUB R0,R0, #0x01
    CMP R0,#0x01
    BNE LOOP

    END
```

Comment: load it into a register first then use the register

Comment: why the mvn? instead of a mov?

Comment: countless examples of how to load a value into a register in arm, did you search so before asking the question?

Comment: @old_timer thanks for the info where do i load the register?

Comment: before you use it, try ldr r2,=0x1001 .  then if you insist on MVN then MVN r2,r2, why are you negating the value?

Comment: if that doesnt work then mov r2,#0x1000 . then add r2,r2,#1